# Autowiring based on generic types in Spring. How does it work?

Tags: java, spring, generics, type-erasure

As you know, there is a new feature in Spring 4: **autowiring based on generic types**.
It's very useful, but I wonder, how Spring developers were able to bypass type erasure, which had prevented them to develop such feature before.

Comment: Based on http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics it's black magic :D

Comment: There's no black magic here, just a bunch of calls to the built-in, JDK reflection classes. Organizing those calls behind ResolvableType doesn't add magic. ProTip: there's no such thing as black magic in programming. Just code you haven't read yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erasure means that the information is gone from the *runtime*. It's still there in the compile-time information, which you can access through reflection. At a rough level, you can think of it that generic information about individual *instances* is erased, but generic information about *classes* is not.

For instance, here's a simple program that defines a generic method `foo` and then prints out the generic information about it from `main`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class GenericReflection {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method m = GenericReflection.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
    System.out.println(m.getGenericReturnType());
  }

  public static List<String> foo() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Output:

> java.util.List<java.lang.String>

As you can see, it's not too complex when you get down to it.

`Method.getGenreicReturnType` returns a [`java.lang.reflect.Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html), which has a few subclasses. One is `ParameterizedType`, which has a method [`getActualTypeArguments`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments) that returns the actual types that this type is parameterized to. Those types might also be generic, of course, which is why it returns a `Type[]` and not `Class[]`. In the `foo` example above, it'd return an array with one element, representing `String`:

```
ParameterizedType pm = (ParameterizedType) m.getGenericReturnType();
Type[] pmArgs = pm.getActualTypeArguments();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pmArgs));
```

> [class java.lang.String]

There are similar "generic" methods for [`Field.getGenericType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType--). You can use this information to find out that `List<String>` is a `List` parameterized to `String`, which is exactly the information they need.

Comment: But Spring decides at runtime, object of which class to inject. So how does framework do it, when there are two equal classes (with Object instead of generic type - as a result of a type erasure) only with different names? Does it someway use typecasts? O_o Or am I completely misunderstand the situation? :)

Comment: If you'll notice, I also did it at runtime. I'll edit to make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: Seems like I understand.. So, there is metadata somewhere in class-file, where all types are stored, type erasure is actually not full erasure and their `ResolvableType`, containing more than a thousand lines, only invokes `getActualTypeArguments()` from JDK's `ParameterizedType`?

Comment: Yup. If you look at the code for ResolvableType, you'll see that most of it is just "helper" code to answer specific questions given a Type (and a bit of other stuff, but basically just that). It actually doesn't even call getActualTyoeArguments directly: it provides helpers to navigate the type info (get the nested type, for instance) and then provides a method getType() to provide the underlying Type.

Comment: (I haven't read `ResolvableType` in super depth, or its usages at all... but that's generally how it's done. The main point of my answer was to illustrate that erasure does not mean that all information is erased from the class metadata.)

Answer (score 4):

The most important details are in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) article from the Spring Blog.

As you can see, all the magic is hidden inside the `ResolvableType` class whose Javadoc you can find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html) and its code can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/381ccde48d11ef82c371789898e563233141b7ee/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.java) (it's a pretty heavy reading :))

Comment: Thank you, I've watched this Blog page, but didn't understand, how does it actually work. If you did, can you explain in simple words, please? :)

Comment: I had looked at it a while back, but I can't say I really remember what was exactly is going on there. It seems that we need to both get are hands dirty reading it! Great question by the way!